# ORA-6502 Character string buffer too small error with Execute immediate statement

Tags: oracle, execute-immediate

I get an Oracle error `ORA-6502 Character string buffer too small` in my code at the statement below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :project_id :=   
               Activity_API.Get_Project_Id(:activity_seq); END;'
USING OUT project_id_, activity_seq_
```

`project_id_` - this is a local variable in the function
`activity_seq_` -- this is an IN parameter to the function.

I don't understand the cause of the error. Besides, the error is not consistently showing up.

Please help me know what am I missing out.
Thanks.

Comment: Some `VARCHAR` variable is been assigned with a string of length greater than it's defined size. Depends upon the data only.

Comment: What is the full error stack - is the error from that assignment, or from within the function you're calling? What size is `project_id_` declared as in your function? What's the maximum possible length of value that the function can return?

Comment: I have checked the size of the project_id_ variable. It is the same as the one returned by the Get_Project_ID function here. Besides there is no size issue even within the Get_Project_id function.

Besides, the error is thrown from within the outer function from this very line where the execute immediate is called.

As I said, the error is not consistent so it makes it even more difficult to understand the real cause of the error.

Comment: If the error is coming from that line, and the stack doesn't refer to the function, then the function is returning a value that is longer than you expect. Try to isolate an `activity_seq_` value that causes the error; or make your variable large and check it after it's fetched. We can't see your function or your data so you need to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this error means that you have a VARCHAR(N) variable somewhere in your code and you tried to assign VARCHAR(N+x) value to it. It may happens anywhere, say:

- size of activity_seq_ is too big for function local variable
- size of project_id_ is too small for function result
- there is some oversized value used into the function itself
- etc.

Sometimes it may happens because of multibyte character set used, say, if value is VARCHAR(N chars) while assignment target is VARCHAR(n bytes). Anyway, you should just debug it. Use PL/SQL Developer or any other tool which can trace stored procedures row by row, run your statement into the test window and see what happens, where and why.